# Exoclick adult ads on mobile website with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, ads

I'm having an issue using Exoclick adult advertisement to advertise on a mobile website using JQuery UI.

I don't know how much I can disclose here until it goes too far into "adult" that I can't post it here anymore.

The Exoclick banners show, but only once! Navigating inside the site doesn't the same ad again (we have two ads, bottom and top. Each is only loaded ONCE per site traversal). If you refresh using the refresh function of the browser ("F5"), they will load again... But only once.

Alright, Exoclick gives me a snippet like this:

```
<!-- BEGIN ExoClick.com Ad Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://syndication.exoclick.com/ads.php?type=300x50&login=<username>&cat=110&search=&ad_title_color=0000cc&bgcolor=FFFFFF&border=0&border_color=000000&font=&block_keywords=&ad_text_color=000000&ad_durl_color=008000&adult=0&sub=&text_only=0&show_thumb=&idzone=<zone id>&idsite=<site id>"></script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript. Update it for a better user experience.</noscript>
<!-- END ExoClick.com Ad Code --></div>
```

The thing is, this works perfectly on static sites, but due to the nature of JQuery Mobile to fetch everything using AJAX, the scripts would be loaded many times over into the browser's execution context (at least this is what I suppose happens!) and in the end... not even execute anymore?

What I already thought of:

- Cache the output of the Exoclick ad script (is there something like "outputcache" for JS?)
- Deactivate Ajax

I tried deactivating Ajax requests but for some reason this didn't do anything:

```
    <script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Are there any cache-busting query parameters being tacked onto the URL the ajax requests are using? e.g. appending the system time so you get a 'new' url each time?

Comment: No, the PHP in the background isn't tacking anything on. Also theres no caches working on the server side either!

Comment: Not the php - the jquery doing the ajax request.

Comment: @MarcB As I said, nothing is tacked on, not by PHP (string concatenation, heh) nor by Javascript/Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it... @bobek indirectly brought me to this answer.

What I did is create an invisible div which contains the ads at first. Then, on pageinit, I steal the div and remove it from DOM. The div will now have an iframe inside made by Exoclick.

Then, without the script by exoclick, I insert it back into the dom on each page init event...

To prevent that the script gets inserted back into the dom, on the server side I check for the X-REQUESTED-WITH header. If it's XMLHttpRquest, I don't send the ads.

This is how it looks in code:

The temporary ad placement, ANYWHERE on the site:

```
<div id="ads">
    <div style="display: none" id="topad">
        <?php require("./_topbannerb.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none" id="bottomad">
        <?php require("./_bottombannerb.php"); ?>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The two PHP files contain the  tags by exoclick. Nothing else.

A script in the head tag:

```
<script>
ads = "";
first = true;

$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {

if (first) {
    ads = $("#ads");
    ads.remove();
}

first = false;

$.each($(".adt"), function(i, v) {
    $(v).append($(ads).children("#topad").first().children("div").clone())
});

$.each($(".adb"), function(i, v) {
    $(v).append($(ads).children("#bottomad").first().children("div").clone())
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Then, where the ads are supposed to be placed in the end:

```
<div class="adt"> </div>
```

The script automatically inserts into each ad placement. Here I have two different ad regions: Top and bottom. Both have no differences except how exoclick handles them in the back.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivating Ajax should work:

```
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {


             $.mobile.addBackBtn = false;
             $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
             $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;

         });
```

On the other hand, you can refresh/reload your script on each ajax success

```
$('html').ajaxSuccess(function() {
  //reload your script using js, plenty of that on google
});
```

Comment: I got more to the bottom of this... The issue is that a document.write call will never proc inside a ajax loaded page... So what I did was make a hidden div with the ad and copy it.. But this hidden div: WHERE the heck do I put it or what do I do with it that it doesnt get reloaded!? :D